# Are thunk and function currying the same?

Tags: javascript, currying, thunk

When I learn thunk, I think they are like function currying. Why is it called thunk?

Thunk

```
function add(x, y){
  return x + y
}

function thunk() {
  return add(10, 20)
}
```

Function currying

```
function multiply(a, b, c) {
    return a * b * c;
}

function multiply(a) {
    return (b) => {
        return (c) => {
            return a * b * c
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No they are quite different.

However, both `thunks` and `currying` have applications in `functional programming`.

#### Thunks

Thunks are a `functional programming` technique used to delay computation.

This helps us greatly in context of `redux`.

So, what do we do when we want to delay computation when we `dispatch` an action?
We use `thunks` as a middleware.

It is very simple

```
export default function thunkMiddleware({ dispatch, getState }) {
  return next => action =>
    typeof action === 'function' ?
      action(dispatch, getState) :
      next(action);
}
```

This is largely the implementation of `thunks` in `redux-thunk`.

It basically just checks whether the `dispatched` action is a function, if not it just passes it as is.

You can read the core implementation [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js). It is just 14 lines.

#### Currying

Currying is converting a single function of n arguments into n functions with a single argument each.

So for example if we have a function that takes three parameters a,b & c

```
let result = fn(a,b,c)
```

When we apply currying to it, then it becomes

```
let applyCurrying = curriedFn(fn);
let result = applyCurrying(a)(b)(c);
```

A trivial implementation of curriedFn:

```
const curriedFn = a => b => c => ( do compuation with a,b,c );
```

In currying, each function takes exactly one parameter.

Comment: For those wondering about **why** and when to use currying, this blog post explains it well: https://medium.com/dailyjs/why-the-fudge-should-i-use-currying-84e4000c8743

Comment: Isn't the above thunk example same as saying,            thunkMiddleware = a => next => action => ( do compuation with a,next, action )         , where a has properties dispatch and getState. In thiat case, how is it differnt than currying?

Answer (score 1):

No, they're quite different. Both might be functions, but that's it. A [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) does not take any parameters, so that you can just evaluate it (and evaluating it at a point of your choosing is the entire purpose), while [function currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is all about parameters and their representation.